# Creat react app is not installing in windows 10

Tags: create-react-app

I had installed the create-react-app with no build configuration in my windows10 Pc got this error. I try in administrator role also I got this same error 
[image]

if any one knows please tell me how to resolve

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. It doesn't have permissions to delete the file at `J:\Freelance\car-react-app\node_modules\nan\package.json`. It is pretty clear `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator`.

Comment: @CharlieFish if you don't the solution, please don't answer for the question,

Comment: I just told you the solution...

Comment: @CharlieFish is right, achu. You need to open the prompt as administrator otherwise you'll have permission errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run with antivirus disabled (if you use Windows Defender, turn off Real-Time protection and Cloud-based protection).It worked for me!

Hope it Helps!!!

Comment: TERRIBLE idea. Suggesting people disable security software??? Seriously...

Answer (score 0):

Try with yarn or lower npm version.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/create/

Hope issue will be fixed.